# Error - TS2769: No overload matches this call. - On ngOnInit

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, api

I am trying to connect an API to a front end. The following is my code:

Task-view.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TaskService } from 'src/app/task.service';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-task-view',
  templateUrl: './task-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./task-view.component.scss']
})
export class TaskViewComponent implements OnInit {

  lists!: any[];
  tasks!: any[];

  constructor(private taskService: TaskService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
  
ngOnInit() {
      this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
       // console.log(params);
        this.taskService.getTasks(params.listId).subscribe((tasks: any[] ) => {
          this.tasks =tasks;
        })

      })

    this.taskService.getLists().subscribe((lists: any[]) => {
    this.lists=lists;

    })
  }
}
```

Task-view.component.html

```
<div class="centered-content">
  <div class="task-manager-container">

    <div class="sidebar has-background-white">
      <h1 class="title has-text-primary">
        Lists
      </h1>

      <div class="list-menu">
        <a class="list-menu-item" is-active>
          <p> list #1</p>
        </a>
        <a class="list-menu-item" *ngFor="let list of lists" [routerLink]="['/lists',list._id]"
          routerLinkActive="is-active">
          <p> {{list.title}}</p>
        </a>
      </div>


      <button class="button is-primary has-text-white" routerLink="/new-list">+ New List</button>

    </div>

    <div class="task-list-container has-background-light">
      <h1 class="title has-text-primary">
        Tasks
      </h1>

      <!-- Task Elements -->
      <div class="task" class="task" *ngfor="let task of tasks">
        <p>{{task.title}}</p>
        </a>
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
```

After I type the ngOnInit from a tutorial my program broke:

```
ngOnInit() {
      this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
       // console.log(params);
        this.taskService.getTasks(params.listId).subscribe((tasks: any[] ) => {
          this.tasks =tasks;
        })

      })

    this.taskService.getLists().subscribe((lists: any[]) => {
    this.lists=lists;

    })
  }
}
```

task.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { WebRequestService } from './web-request.service';
//import { Task } from './models/task.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TaskService {

  constructor(private webReqService: WebRequestService) { }


  getLists() {
    return this.webReqService.get('lists');
  }

  createList(title: string) {
    // We want to send a web request to create a list
    return this.webReqService.post('lists', { title });
  }

  getTasks(listId: string) {
    return this.webReqService.get(`lists/${listId}/tasks`);
  }

}
```

web-request.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WebRequestService {

  readonly ROOT_URL;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.ROOT_URL = 'http://localhost:3000';
  }

  get(uri: string) {
    return this.http.get(`${this.ROOT_URL}/${uri}`);
  }

  post(uri: string, payload: Object) {
    return this.http.post(`${this.ROOT_URL}/${uri}`, payload);
  }

  patch(uri: string, payload: Object) {
    return this.http.patch(`${this.ROOT_URL}/${uri}`, payload);
  }

  delete(uri: string) {
    return this.http.delete(`${this.ROOT_URL}/${uri}`);
  }
}
```

This is the error I got. Any thoughts?

> Build at: 2020-12-01T03:14:29.853Z - Hash: 3639e8cffc68651ef24b -
> Time: 15491ms
>
> Error: src/app/pages/task-view/task-view.component.ts:24:60 - error
> TS2769: No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 5, '(observer?:
> NextObserver | ErrorObserver |
> CompletionObserver | undefined): Subscription', gave the
> following error.
> Argument of type '(tasks: any[]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NextObserver | ErrorObserver |
> CompletionObserver | undefined'.
> Property 'complete' is missing in type '(tasks: any[]) => void' but required in type 'CompletionObserver'.   Overload 2 of 5,
> '(next?: ((value: Object) => void) | undefined, error?: ((error: any)
> => void) | undefined, complete?: (() => void) | undefined): Subscription', gave the following error.
> Argument of type '(tasks: any[]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Object) => void'.
> Types of parameters 'tasks' and 'value' are incompatible.
> Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.
> The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
>
> 24         this.taskService.getTasks(params.listId).subscribe((tasks:
> any[] ) => {
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts:64:5
> 64     complete: () => void;
> ~~~~~~~~
> 'complete' is declared here. src/app/pages/task-view/task-view.component.ts:30:43 - error TS2769:
> No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 5, '(observer?:
> NextObserver | ErrorObserver |
> CompletionObserver | undefined): Subscription', gave the
> following error.
> Argument of type '(lists: any[]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NextObserver | ErrorObserver |
> CompletionObserver | undefined'.
> Property 'complete' is missing in type '(lists: any[]) => void' but required in type 'CompletionObserver'.   Overload 2 of 5,
> '(next?: ((value: Object) => void) | undefined, error?: ((error: any)
> => void) | undefined, complete?: (() => void) | undefined): Subscription', gave the following error.
> Argument of type '(lists: any[]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Object) => void'.
> Types of parameters 'lists' and 'value' are incompatible.
> The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
> Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type 'any[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.
>
> 30     this.taskService.getLists().subscribe((lists: any[]) => {
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts:64:5
> 64     complete: () => void;
> ~~~~~~~~
> 'complete' is declared here.
>
> ** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **

Comment: Seems like the problem points to your service, but would like to confirm. May we see your Task Service? that would help us debug the problem :)

Comment: @KShewengger Thank you so much for helping me. I added my task-service.ts and web-request.service.ts.

Comment: Hi Camila, no problem :) Have answered it below, looking forward to your response :)

Comment: are building to-do app of MEAN stack by intellipaat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your service and `ngOnInit` code. Seems like the type that you have specified on your `this.taskService.getTasks` and `this.taskService.getLists` doesn't correlate with the return type of your service

**Your Code**

```
.subscribe((tasks: any[] ) => { ... })
```

**Change it to `any` without `[]`**

```
.subscribe((tasks: any ) => {
   console.log(tasks);                   // Check the tasks if it's actually an array response 
                                         // or is actually an object where your array resides
 
})
```

---

For Debugging purposes, it may also be best to check if what is the response of these routes that you're accessing to and if they do have a response and to confirm if it's in array type

```
http://localhost:3000/lists
http://localhost:3000/lists/<LIST_ID>/tasks
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! Thank you so much. I just started learning the language. I appreciate all your help!!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the exact object return type then use **any** in object declaration, and API call response. Your code should be as below

Task-view.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TaskService } from 'src/app/task.service';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-task-view',
  templateUrl: './task-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./task-view.component.scss']
})
export class TaskViewComponent implements OnInit {

  lists!: any;
  tasks!: any;

  constructor(private taskService: TaskService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
  
ngOnInit() {
      this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
       // console.log(params);
        this.taskService.getTasks(params.listId).subscribe((tasks: any ) => {
          this.tasks =tasks;
        })

      })

    this.taskService.getLists().subscribe((lists: any) => {
    this.lists=lists;
    })
  }
}
```